# How do you run functions and variables from shell script into docker?

Tags: wordpress, bash, shell, docker

so I am trying to work out what the best way to call this function in my bash script so that is executed in the docker container.

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_BUCKET="https://s3-bucket-location.com"
AWS_BUCKET_DEV_FILE="devfile.zip"
AWS_BUCKET_PIC_FILE="WORDPRESSpics.zip"

wordpress_production_S3_download () {
cd /tmp/
wget $AWS_BUCKET/$AWS_BUCKET_PIC_FILE
mv $AWS_BUCKET_PIC_FILE /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2017
cd /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2017
unzip $AWS_BUCKET_PIC_FILE
rm $AWS_BUCKET_PIC_FILE
chown -R www-data:www-data 12/
}
```

My thought to run this function in the docker container is something like this

```
docker exec -ti dockerwordpressmaster_mysql_1 bash -c "wordpress_production_S3_download"
```

but I get

> bash: wordpress_production_S3_download: command not found

I have also tried to subsite the function into the variable 
i.e

```
test=$(wordpress_production_S3_download)

docker exec -ti dockerwordpressmaster_mysql_1 bash -c "$test"
```

but the function "variable" test only executes on the local machine and not in the Docker container like I would like.

Any help with the issue is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the script file containing the function into the `dockerwordpressmaster_mysql_1` container and then execute it.

```
docker cp wordpress-script.sh dockerwordpressmaster_mysql_1:wordpress-script.js
docker exec -ti dockerwordpressmaster_mysql_1 bash -c "source wordpress-script.sh && wordpress_production_S3_download"
```